# Most performant way of duplicating rows within an array

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I have an array of arrays that looks like this.

```
[
  [1, "a", ...],
  [2, "a", ...],
  [3, "a", ...],
  [4, "a", ...],
]
```

This array may be arbitrarily big, though assume for now that it fits easily enough into memory, with enough overhead to process an individual row but not enough to hold a duplicate of the entire array.

I need to perform some work on each row in the array that may result in some rows (maybe a few, maybe all of them) being expanded into multiple rows.  The new rows need to be ordered so that they follow on from where the original row was located.  For example, the final array may look like this:

```
[
  [1, "a", ...],
  [2, "a", ...],
  [2, "b", ...],
  [2, "c", ...],
  [3, "a", ...],
  ...
  [3, "z", ...],
  [4, "a", ...],
]
```

As the array may be large (both in width and height) I need this to be as performant as possible.  My gut feeling is that most sane methods for handling this would have broadly similar memory requirements (with total memory required being a small amount more than the memory required for the finished array).

However, it is less clear to me what the fastest method is.

## Possible solutions

Here are some suggested algorithms, but there are no doubt countless others.  What method will give the best performance?

- **Method 1:** Use a loop to iterate over array, use `array_splice()` to insert any new rows.
- **Method 2:** Use `array_shift()` to remove a row from original array, insert original and new rows into results array using `$arrResults[] = $Row`.
- **Method 3:** User `array_pop()` to remove a row from the original array, insert original and new rows into results using `array_unshift()`.
- **Method 4:** As method 2, but use `array_reverse()` before starting and then use `array_pop()` instead of `array_shift()`.
- **Method 5:** As method 3, but use `$arrResults[] = $Row` instead of `array_unshift()` and then use `array_reverse()` on the final array.

## My thoughts

1. [`array_shift()` is slower than `array_pop()`](https://cmljnelson.blog/2018/10/16/phps-array_shift-performance/).
2. Therefore, presumably, `array_unshift()` is slower than `array_push()`.
3. I also assume (but have not tested) that using the `[]` operator is the equal to or faster than `array_push()`.
4. `array_splice()` sounds like it will be slow, similar to `array_shift()` as it will require a complete re-index.  I don't know if implementation differences would favour one over the other, but presumably both are slower than the `array_push()`, in which case any distinction is moot.
5. The `array_reverse()` method avoids any re-indexing during the loop, which feels like it might therefore be the quickest method.  However, I would be concerned about the memory requirements.
6. Both `array_splice()` and `array_reverse()` return the result, rather than operating in-place, which implies that the memory requirements are double what would be needed if only in-place methods are called.
7. Both methods 4 and 5 will require some extra work to ensure the new rows are added in the appropriate order.  This is not ideal, but it is acceptable if the performance improvement is good enough.

Comment: `array_splice()` works in-place.

Comment: Anything that requires inserting elements in the middle of an array will be slow, because it has to shift all the remaining elements over. It makes the algorithm O(n^2)

Comment: `array_shift()` also requires shifting all the remaining elements, so doing that in a loop will be O(n^2)

Comment: @Barmar - you're correct.  I misread the fact that it returned an array as meaning it returned the updated array, but actually it returns an array containing any removed rows (of which there would be none, in my use-case).  Your point about re-indexing is the point I was trying to make - if we can avoid re-indexing then that would, surely, be faster.

Comment: @Barmar The reason I said the `array_splice()` method would be slower than `array_shift()` method was because I imagined that I would need to call `array_splice()` once for each new row, rather than `array_shift()` which is called once per loop iteration.  However, on closer reading I can see that it's possible to splice multiple rows in one call, so I agree that that there is no difference here.  I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Any algorithm that requires inserting or removing elements at the beginning of middle of the array will be O(n<sup>2</sup>), because these operations have to shift all the following elements in the array. This should generally be avoided when you know you're working with large arrays.

If you can handle the memory load of having two copies of the array temporarily, I recommend you simply push the rows and copies onto the result array without removing them from the original. Then at the end of the loop, replace the original array variable with the result array. The garbage collector will then discard the original array.

Note also that PHP uses copy-on-write when you assign arrays. So all the copies of the rows will share their memory. All you're duplicating temporarily is the array backbone.

If you're modifying the rows after you duplicate them, you can use `unset()` on the original array element to allow its memory to be reclaimed.

Comment: how about just appending new rows at the end, and once you're finished processing use an array_sort?

Comment: That assumes that the array should be sorted.

Comment: @Charles - The correct sort order for the original rows is based on the original (numeric) array keys, so the array is not sortable post-fact.

Comment: Re: copy-on-write, the array does need to have some tidying performed on it (data normalisation) which would mean that some array values get modified.  I was planning on doing this inside the loop, but it could be avoided by doing a second pass after the new rows are inserted.  Or, possibly, a first pass, prior to creating expanding the duplicates.

Comment: @HappyDog Use `unset()` on the original array element after you're done making the duplicates.

Comment: That's a thought.  An `unset()` on the original array presumably doesn't trigger any re-indexing, just frees up the space used by the original row data.  So for an array that has `C` columns, starts out as `R1` rows, ends up as `R2` rows, the memory requirements would be ~ `(R2 * C) + R1`, i.e. the final array + the original index data.  The 'working' row would not be modified before the `unset()` call, so we don't need to add an extra `C` as we might in languages that copy on assignment.